# change a specific line of a file using awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file which I want to modify in a specific line.  I had use this:

```
#!/bin/bash/
cp /dir1/dir2/FILE_to_be_modified . ;
var ="$1 $1 $1";
awk -v li=4 -v new="$var" '{
        if (NR==li) {
                  print new;
        } else {
                 print $O;
        }
}' FILE_to_be_modified>>new_FILE
```

with this I could modified line 4 of `FILE_to_be_modified` but always with patterns like `9 9 9` `12 12 12`, now I'd like something like `9 9 11` or `12 12 14`. I've tried silly thinks like changing `var` to `$1 $1 $1+2`. should I use `bc`?

Comment: need to remove the trailing slash from the shebang line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash arithmetic:

```
var = "$1 $1 $(($1 + 2))"
```

Have a look at [the docs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) and [the tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-10.html#ss10.2).

Comment: thank you very much for your help and for the links!!! 
I think it is not necessary to say that it worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

When you write `var ="$1 $1 $1"`, you let `bash`, not `awk`, expand the variables. `$1` accidentally has a meaning both in `awk` and in `bash`. So what you do now is replace the line with 3 occurrences of the first argument passed to your script. By changing it to e.g. `var ="$1 $2 $3"` you will use the 3 first parameters passed to your script. If, on the other hand, your goal is to replace the line with the values of first field as seen by `awk`, use a single quote: `var ='$1 $1 $1'`. This way `bash` won't expand it, only `awk` will and if you change it to `var ='$1 $2 $3'` you will be replacing the line with the first 3 fields of original value (as seen by `awk`).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could hand off the arithmetic to awk

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -v li=4 -v val="$1" '
    NR==li {print val, val, val+2; next}
    {print}
' /dir1/dir2/FILE_to_be_modified >> ./new_FILE
```